# Consulta mysql con eloquent laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, controller

como seria la siguiente consulta utilizando eloquent?

```
SELECT value1, value2, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM Doctor 
INNER JOIN Hospital ON hospital_id = idHospital 
INNER JOIN ciudad  ON ciudad_id = idCiudad 
GROUP BY idHospital;
```

En mi controller tengo (NO FUNCIONA):

```
$lista = Doctor::with('hospitales', 'ciudades')->groupBy('apMaterno')->count();
```

En mi model Doctor:

```
public function Hospitales(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Hospital::class,'hospital_id');
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: qué representan value1 y value2? Si son los apellidos, qué sentido tiene agruparlos...? Es para ver cuántos parientes trabajan en el rubro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es exactamente esa consulta en Eloquent sería esto:

```php
$lista = Doctor::select(['value1', 'value2'])
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as TOTAL')
    ->join('Hospital', 'hospital_id', 'idHospital')
    ->join('ciudad', 'ciudad_id', 'idCiudad')
    ->groupBy('idHospital')
    ->get();
```

No entiendo muy bien cuál es la finalidad de la consulta, pero si necesitas el total de doctores por hospital puedes hacer algo como:

```php
// Models/Hospital.php
public function doctors()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Doctor::class, 'idHospital');
}
```

```php
// Controlador
Hospital::withCount('doctors')->get();
```

Comment: Tienes razón, me faltaba el get(). El agrupamiento que puse es el mismo que él tiene en el SQL, eso se consigue quitando el ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY del sql_mode. No es lo ideal, pero es lo que él necesita.

Answer (score 0):

en vez de count() al final por que no usas get()?

ejemplo:

$consulta = Clase::where(...)->get();

$cantidad = count($consulta);

Comment: lo que pasa es q quiero contar el toral, fijate en el query sql, que puse al princiipio

Comment: puedes hacer tu consulta normal por ejemplo $algo = Algo::where(algo)->get(),  Entonces para contar luego haces $cantidad = count($algo);